# json data not being displayed in result div

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using a form tutorial that shows how to handle errors and return to the page via json. I can see in chrome that the json response is being sent but it is not being displayed in the result div. That is blank. In chrome in the element tab I can see that the information is being inserted just not displayed. If someone could show me why this is happening I would be grateful. Thanks

source showing as entered

```
<div id="brtv-result" style="display: none; " class="success error">You must enter a service level</div>
```

jquery

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "boxrtrvtemp.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
          $("#brtv-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#brtv-result").html(msg.message);
     },
      error:function(){
         $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
         $("#brtv-result").addClass('error');
         $("#brtv-result").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
     }
   });
```

the php

```
<?php

//response array with status code and message
$response_array = array();

//validate the post form

//check the name field
if(empty($authorised)){

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'Name cannot be blank';

//check the email field
} elseif(empty($serivce)) {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'You must enter a service level';

//check the message field
} elseif($department=="Choose Department") {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'You must select a department';

//form validated. send email
} elseif($address=="Choose Address") {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'You must select a retrieveal address';

//form validated. send email
} elseif(empty($boxnumber)) {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'You must enter a box for retrieveal';

//form validated. send email
}else {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    $response_array['message'] = 'All items retrieved successfully';

}

//send the response back
echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have to show the div i think because it starts out hidden:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "boxrtrvtemp.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
          $("#brtv-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#brtv-result").html(msg.message);
          $("#brtv-result").show()//show it
     },
      error:function(){
         $("#brtv-result").removeClass('success');
         $("#brtv-result").addClass('error');
         $("#brtv-result").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
          $("#brtv-result").show()//show it
     }
   });
```

Comment: Can you tell me, is the error in the php supposed to be return in the success or error part of the ajax. If the status == error then for some reason the result is coming through the success function and causing the form to reset. Thanks

Comment: The function that you tie to "error" is triggered only when there is an error in the call itself: for example, the url you are calling doesn't respond. To check if the php returned an error you should check `if( msg.status === 'error')`

Answer (score 1):

Your div is set to `style="display: none; "`

Comment: What about when the HTML element is already displayed when the page is loaded? I can change the displayed text in the HTML element in the "error" function.

Comment: @Kingsolmn: I'm sorry. Could you clarify what you're talking about?

Comment: What I am looking for is this: I have a page with a table displayed, and I can modify a <tr> element by adding a single <td> element or changing the contents of that <td> element with jQuery. The problem I am having is adding in more <td> elements.

Comment: It sounds like you have a completely different problem. [Add table row in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) may be relevant. Also see: [How to dynamically add rows very quickly using jQuery](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-dynamically-add-rows-very-quickly-using-jQuery-159.php). If that doesn't help, consider posting a question where we can examine your code. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the links, for some reason I can't make my brain think in JavaScript; guess I'm too used to OOP.